# How do I dismiss a UIView after scanning a barcode?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have an iPad app that I want to add a barcode reader to... this is the code for the initialization of the barcoder code:

```
-(void) scanInitializationCode  {

_highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_highlightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
_highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
_highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
[self.view addSubview:_highlightView];

//  define the label to display the results of the scan
_label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_label.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
_label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15 alpha:0.65];
_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_label.text = @"(none)";
[self.view addSubview:_label];

//  session initialization
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
_device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;

//  define the input device
_input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
if (_input) {
    [_session addInput:_input];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}

//  and output device
_output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_session addOutput:_output];

_output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

//  and preview layer
_prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
_prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
_prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];
```

}

This is the AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection  {

CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
NSString *detectionString = nil;
NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code];

for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
    for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
        if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
        {
            barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
            highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
            detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (detectionString != nil)  {

        _label.text = detectionString;
        oISBNField.text = detectionString;  //  move detectionString to ISBN textbox
        [_session stopRunning];
        [_highlightView removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
    else
        _label.text = @"(none)";
}
```

This is the code that starts the scanning process by having the user tap a UIButton:

```
 - (IBAction)aReadBarcode:(UIButton *)sender {

[self scanInitializationCode];

[_session startRunning];

//  display the activity
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_highlightView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_label];

oISBNField.text = scanResults;

}
```

The problem is that once the scan has found the barcode, it stays visible; what I want to do is have it return to the UIView that has the button that caused it to start scanning (in other words, I want the *_highlightView* to disappear).  I have tried all kinds of "dismissal" methods, even putting it at the back of the z-order, but none of them work.  How can I make the *highlightView* disappear from the screen?

Comment: Just saying: is `highlightView` the view you really want to remove? What about `prevLayer`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

> [_prevLayer removeFromSuperlayer]; after [_session stopRunning]